# Image Recognition of Known Images in Unknown Settings

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

Imagine I have an image database of 10,000 detailed images (e.g. photos ), and I want to recognise them when in another setting, for example framed on the wall, or as a poster in a bus stop, so not the exact images, but printed out and then maybe with glare or at a different angle and within another image.

I could make a training set of one of the images in different settings ( hanging on the wall, at a bus stop ) but I have too many images to do this manually for each image.

I can think of one way, where I create a computer program to insert an image in various locations and use that as a training set ( e.g. 10,000 images times X locations/settings ) but that would be a very large training set.

Is there another way to do this without a specific training set for each image? Ideally once the model is trained, I can give it image 10,001 and it will recognise it in various settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done with feature based methods like SIFT, SURF etc. These create image descriptors  that are rather robust to a variety of distortions and do not require training.

Note however, that with 10K images, you mileage may vary.
The results depend on the resolution of the unseen images, the amount of actual image features in each of the 10K images and how similar they are to each other.